# Woocommerce API per_page max limit in react native

Tags: javascript, php, react-native, woocommerce, woocommerce-rest-api

I am building an ecommerce mobile app with react native and woocommerce and i an facing this issue.. per_page doesn't work

This is the code

```
import WooCommerceAPI from 'react-native-woocommerce-api';

const WooCommerce = new WooCommerceAPI({
  url: 'http://example.com/', // Your store URL
  ssl: false,
  consumerKey: 'ck_xxxxxxxxxxx', // Your consumer key
  consumerSecret: 'cs_xxxxxxxxxxx', // Your consumer secret
  wpAPI: true, // Enable the WP REST API integration
  version: 'wc/v3', // WooCommerce WP REST API version
  queryStringAuth: true
});
```

Then

```
  componentDidMount() {
    WooCommerce.get('products?per_page=50', {})
      .then(res => {
        this.setState({
          data: res,
          isLoading: false
        });

      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
        this.setState({
          error,
          isLoading: true
        });
      });
  }
```

and then

```
    console.log(this.state.data);
```

and i got this in console

Object {
  "code": "woocommerce_rest_authentication_error",
  "data": Object {
    "status": 401,
  },
  "message": "Invalid signature - provided signature does not match.",
}

If i write `WooCommerce.get('products', {})` it gets 10 products as a max limit from woocommerce API but i need to get all products

Comment: Do other calls work for you? the error you are receiving is an auth error, either the key\secret is incorrect or you are not sending the auth header.

Comment: `WooCommerce.get('products', {})` this line works fine.. this error happens when i add a parameter like this  `WooCommerce.get('products?per_page=50', {})`

Comment: try this move the parameters into the data object such as: `WooCommerce.get('products', {'per_page': 50}).then(...).catch(...)`
Also, if you are using windows, try to see what the request looks like with Fiddler, or using the Chrome DevTools network tab (or its firefox equivelent)

Comment: I tried this way.. and it brings this error Object {
  "code": "woocommerce_rest_authentication_error",
  "data": Object {
    "status": 401,
  },
  "message": "Invalid signature - provided signature does not match.",
}

Comment: Is there a way for you to log the requests? what headers are being sent?

Comment: First, thank you for your concern.. second, i followed these instructions https://github.com/JamesUgbanu/react-native-woocommerce-api

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open **react-native-woocommerce-api.js** in **node_modules\react-native-woocommerce-api\lib\**

then goto line 195 (_getOAuth().authorize function) and change:

```
params.qs = this._getOAuth().authorize({
  url: url,
  method: method
});
```

to

```
params.qs = this._getOAuth().authorize({
  url: url + '?' + this.join(data, '&'),
  method: method
});
```

Comment: No dear, this is the only solution worked for me... i searched too much for more than a month and this is the only solution worked.. just add `+ '?' + this.join(data, '&'),` to the url inside  react-native-woocommerce-api.js file

Answer (score 1):

```
 WooCommerce.get('products?per_page=100&page=1', {}) // YOu can set a Variable in-place of 1 and index 100 is the limit
```

Older API version

```
https://Yoursite/wc-api/v3/products?filter[limit] =-1
```

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you for reply... but it doesn't solve.. i still getting the same error

Comment: What error? ```Object { "code": "woocommerce_rest_authentication_error", "data": Object { "status": 401, }, "message": "Invalid signature - provided signature does not match.", }``` That one?

Comment: Yes, that's it dear

Comment: okay Thats a Authentication issue, which means your secret is not working or your userdetails or something of the sort is wrong its not to do with the Product per page filter

Comment: But it works fine when I get products without any parameters like that ('products')

Answer (score 0):

```
 WooCommerce.get('products', {per_page: 50})
  .then(res => {
    this.setState({
      data: res,
      isLoading: false
    });

  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.log(error);
    this.setState({
      error,
      isLoading: true
    });
  });
```

this should work!